# <Enter>, <Leave> in Tkinter respond badly and how to keep the whole frame size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm beginner.
I'm making a program when the mouse cursor is entering the area, the buttons are shown and when the cursor is leaving the area, the buttons are invisible.
But, especially Leave sometimes responds badly.
Are there any alternatives to realize this program?
Also, I want to keep the whole frame size even when the buttons are shown.
How can I keep the Frame size?

```
import tkinter as Tk
Class Frame(Tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


        self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
        self.f.pack()

        self.text_frame = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.text_frame.pack()
        self.text_frame.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)

        self.text_la = Tk.Label(self.text_frame, text='Hello!')
        self.text_la.pack()

        self.f_button = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.f_button.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button1')
        self.button.pack(padx=5, pady=5, side=Tk.LEFT)
        self.button2 = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button2')
        self.button2.pack(padx=5, pady=5,side=Tk.LEFT)

        self.listbox = Tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.text_frame.pack_forget()
        self.f_button.pack()

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.f_button.pack_forget()
        self.text_frame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

f = Frame()
f.pack()
f.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to fix your indentation in the provided code above using **`{}`** button, and with the equation of: `an indentation = 4 spaces` in mind.

Comment: What does "respond badly" mean?

Comment: _"I want to keep the whole frame size even when the buttons are shown. How can I keep the Frame size?"_ I think you should be able to do that unsetting the flag for [`pack_propagate`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_propagate-method). As in `f.pack_propagate(False)` for example.

Comment: Respond badly means sometimes it doesn't respond.
Seems like the listbox below the Frame causes it.
Only when the mouse cursor leave though the listbox, Leave sometimes doesn't respond.

Comment: @spider_hand Please make sure the code you've provided runs without error(s).

Comment: Your code seems to work for me 100% of the time. Are you aware that `text_frame` doesn't expand to fill the whole width of the window? Maybe when you think it isn't responding it's simply because your cursor isn't over the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `"<Enter>"` and `"<Leave>"` events feel inconsistent because they're bound(`bind`ed) to sub-frames, you can try replacing:

```
self.text_frame.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)
...
self.f_button.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
```

with:

```
self.f.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)
...
self.f.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
```

As `self.f` is the parent to both those frames the events should feel more consistent.

---

You can use [`pack_propagate`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_propagate-method) method to disable that parent's resizing based on its children widgets' size demands. I found it easy to have it disabled right before `self.f` needs to resize from its largest yet required size to a smaller size, which is just before hiding the buttons for me. Since the buttons are hidden in `on_leave` that's the point which you can unset `pack_propagate`'s flag:

```
def on_leave(self, event):
    self.f.pack_propagate(False)
    self.f_button.pack_forget()
    self.text_frame.pack()
```

Working code with suggested modifications:

```
import tkinter as Tk


class Frame(Tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


        self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
        self.f.pack()

        self.text_frame = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.text_frame.pack()
        self.f.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)

        self.text_la = Tk.Label(self.text_frame, text='Hello!')
        self.text_la.default_fg = self.text_la['fg']
        self.text_la.pack()

        self.f_button = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.f.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button1')
        self.button.pack(padx=5, pady=5, side=Tk.LEFT)
        self.button2 = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button2')
        self.button2.pack(padx=5, pady=5,side=Tk.LEFT)

        self.listbox = Tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.text_frame.pack_forget()
        self.f_button.pack()

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.f.pack_propagate(False)
        self.f_button.pack_forget()
        self.text_frame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    f = Frame()
    f.pack()
    f.mainloop()
```

---

Alternatively, you can match `self.text_la`'s text color to that of its `background` color, which would essentially [hide its text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370847/enter-leave-in-tkinter-respond-badly-and-how-to-keep-the-whole-frame-size/48372566#comment83731617_48371736) using:

```
self.text_la['fg'] = self.text_la['bg']
```

Also in order to restore it back to its initial make sure to first put its text color in an attribute like:

```
self.text_la.initial_fg = self.text_la['fg']
```

and then assign it back to its text color to restore initial later:

```
self.text_la['fg'] = self.text_la.initial_fg
```

Working code with suggested modifications:

```
import tkinter as Tk
class Frame(Tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


        self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
        self.f.pack()

        self.text_frame = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.text_frame.pack()
        self.f.bind('<Enter>', self.on_enter)

        self.text_la = Tk.Label(self.text_frame, text='Hello!')
        self.text_la.initial_fg = self.text_la['fg']
        self.text_la.pack()

        self.f_button = Tk.Frame(self.f)
        self.f.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)
        self.button = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button1')
        self.button.pack(padx=5, pady=5, side=Tk.LEFT)
        self.button2 = Tk.Button(self.f_button, text='Button2')
        self.button2.pack(padx=5, pady=5,side=Tk.LEFT)

        self.listbox = Tk.Listbox(self)
        self.listbox.pack()

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.text_la['fg'] = self.text_la['bg']
        self.f_button.pack()

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.text_la['fg'] = self.text_la.initial_fg
        self.text_frame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    f = Frame()
    f.pack()
    f.mainloop()
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove the label's text by replacing it with `""`, again though you'd need to save its initial text to restore later; just like you did with the color trick.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! your first suggestion is almost perfect.
But the first way is changing the size of the Frame when i entered the area first time
How can I improve?

Comment: @spider_hand You could move `self.f.pack_propagate(False)` from `on_leave` to `on_enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the `.forget()`? Also, it's not `if name == 'main'`:
So you can write something like:

```
    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.f_button.pack()

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.f_button.forget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Frame()
    f.pack()
    f.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's  the difference between forget() and pack_forget()?

Comment: @spider_hand: `forget()` and `pack_forget()` are identical.

Comment: in fact forget() is a shortcut for pack_forget(). So it's better as you use it because sometime later you will use the grid_forget() and I think there is no shortcut there. But I also changed the 2 functions.

Comment: I want to make the text invisible when the button is shown up.
This way is just to show or hide the button part I think.